# Node.js on Elastic Beanstalk: How to access NODE_HOME?

Tags: node.js, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Elastic beanstalk installs several versions of node.js on each machine in non-standard locations under `/opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-*`. An environment variable `$NODE_HOME` is used to point to the version of node that is in use.

Occasionally it is necessary to `ssh` into the ec2 instance and run `node` or `npm`. However, these are not on the PATH, and so must be added using $NODE_HOME.

How do you find out what $NODE_HOME is set to? How do you programatically add `npm` and `node` to the path of local users?